# Is there a way to track the access to global variables with Android Instrumentation without source code?

Tags: java, android, testing, instrumentation

I want to find out if an application is accessing global variables like `Build.MODEL` without source code (Blackbox). Would this be possible with Android Instrumentation or do you know of another way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The only way If found to do this was to hook the functions with FRIDA.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).